# <use> tag to load svg from external url

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to load svg from external URL by using `<use>` tag so that I can have some more control on my svg instead of `<img>` tag. But when I am using svg on the same page and loading using `<use>` tag it is working perfect. But as I am uploading svg to external URL and putting URL in `<use>` then it is not working.

Working example code

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="display: none;">
<defs>
<g id="icon-image">
  <path class="path1" d="M0 4v26h32v-26h-32zM30 28h-28v-22h28v22zM22 11c0-1.657 1.343-3 3-3s3 1.343 3 3c0 1.657-1.343 3-3 3-1.657 0-3-1.343-3-3zM28 26h-24l6-16 8 10 4-3z"></path>
</defs>
</svg>

<h1>
  Photo Gallery
  <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <use fill="blue" xlink:href="#icon-image"></use>
  </svg>
</h1>
```

But I want something like this (Not Working). I have upload the same svg image on external URL but it is not showing up on the page.

```html
<h1>
  Photo Gallery
  <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <use fill="blue" xlink:href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/instanano/apparatus/test555.svg#icon-image"></use>
  </svg>
</h1>
```

Comment: Take inspiration from [the ``<load-file>`` Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd)

Comment: Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use) *For security reasons, browsers may apply the same-origin policy on use elements and may refuse to load a cross-origin URL in the href attribute.*

Answer (score 0):

As @Robert Longson already has pointed out:
You might not be able to embed external svg symbol/defs references due to security settings.

Provided the external host **permits cross origin access** for svg files, you can use these polyfills:

- [polyfill by @thasmo.](https://github.com/thasmo/external-svg-polyfill)
- [svgxuse by @Keyamoon (icomoon developer/s)](https://github.com/Keyamoon/svgxuse)

CDNs dedicated to script libraries like jsdelivr will usually add suitable CORS headers (or provide some options to allow cross origin access).

On the other hand: svg sharing sites like [svgshare](https://svgshare.com) don't allow remote access (but it works fine for `<img>` elements, but you won't be able to fetch and parse the svg DOM).

#### Example 1: using @thasmo's external-svg-polyfill

For some reasons this polyfill doesn't work in SO snippets on iOs safari

```js
window.document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  new ExternalSvgPolyfill();
});
```

```css
svg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<!--  works! -->
<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <use fill="blue" xlink:href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/instanano/apparatus/test555.svg#icon-image" />
  </svg>

<!--won't work -->
<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <use fill="blue" xlink:href="https://svgshare.com/i/mJH.svg#icon-image" />
</svg>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@thasmo/external-svg-polyfill@2/browser/bundle.min.js"></script>
```

#### Example 2: using svgxuse by @Keyamoon

```css
svg{
  display:inline-block;
  width:25%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <use fill="blue" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/instanano/apparatus/test555.svg#icon-image" />
  </svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <use fill="blue" xlink:href="https://svgshare.com/i/mJH.svg#icon-image" />
  </svg>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svgxuse/1.2.6/svgxuse.min.js"></script>
```

Both polyfills fetch the external svg contents and append it as a hidden inlined `<svg>` element to the DOM.

See also: ([Understanding CORS and SVG](https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/extras/ch10-cors.html))